# Single slave for multiple masters in AWS AuroraDB

Tags: aws, master-slave-replication, aurora

We are planning to use AWS Aurora(MySQL version) as our relational database. There will be three masters in different regions. We need the data from these masters replicated in a single slave. I think in SQLServer, this is possible using log shipping. Aurora MySQL also has bin log shipping but I am not seeing any way to push the logs from different masters in a single slave.

Please advise if anyone has come across and solved this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html